# Error by fast clicking on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, click, selection-api

**Disabling off all JS and CSS, doesn't solve the problem. After fast clicking I still get error.**

I don't understand why it happens.
**jQuery: 1.9.1.**
**Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m**

```
$(".checkbox-list input").click(function(){
    that = $(this);
    that.closest('li').toggleClass('someClass', that.is(':checked'));
});
```

After fast click I'm gettin':

> TypeError: Accessing selectionStart on an input element that cannot have a selection. [http://site.domain/page/anotherPage:848]

I don't get it... The Line #848 doesn't exist at all, my max line is 309.
I think it happens probably because one function executes many times at the same time... ?

Thanks for answering!

### UPD

**Chrome console output:**

Uncaught TypeError: Accessing selectionStart on an input element that cannot have a selection.

- extractContext
- llContent.showDialogForCurrentSelection
- llContent.handlers.dblClick
- commonHandle
- elem.handle

### UPD 2

I found the problem in Chrome extensions "Lingualeo", that have dblclick event on all of the dom elements, that caused this bug.

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: You must be having some other library/code that's trying to get the cursor position, that's what *selectionStart* would be used for. Did you try a global search for that within your project?

Comment: It can be written as `$(".checkbox-list :checkbox").click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.closest('li').toggleClass('AList_selected', that.is(':checked'))
});`

Comment: @dezlab...Can you provide the html code of your problem..

Comment: @OlracVaizard, `<input type="checkbox" name="Alist-checkbox[]" value="<numeric value>"/>`, maybe problem in "[]" in the name attr, but after removing [] I still getting error.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, I turned off all JS files, and still getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for help.
I found the problem in Chrome extensions "Lingua Leo", that have dblclick event on all of the dom elements, that caused this bug.

Answer (score 1):

try use toggleClass.

[here is the link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Comment: toggleClass have a two parameters. the 2nd one is a bool indicating if the class will be added or not.

Comment: thanks for your advice, it's really good remark) but my problem isn't related with this.